# data.table sum by group and return row with max value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in this fashion:

```
dd <- data.table(f = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), g = c(1,2,3,4,5))
dd
```

I need to sum the values `g` by factor `f`, and finally return a single row data.table object that has the maximum value of `g`, but that also contains the factor information. i.e.

```
___f|g   
1: b 9
```

My closest attempt so far is

```
tmp3 <- dd[, sum(g), by = f][, max(V1)]
tmp3
```

Which results in:

```
> tmp3
[1] 9
```

EDIT: I'm ideally looking for a purely data.table piece of code/workflow. I'm surprised that with all the speedy fast split-apply-combine wizardry and ability to subset your data in the form of 'example[i= subset, ]` that I haven't found a straight forward way to subset on a single value condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
library(data.table)
dd <- data.table(
  f = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), 
  g = c(1,2,3,4,5))
##
> dd[,list(g = sum(g)),by=f][which.max(g),]
   f g
1: b 9
```

---

Comment: Works well, though I'm surprised at how relatively complicated this is. My initial (unsuccessful) attempts were focusing on the first data.table argument `i`, which i thought was primarily for selecting your data.

Comment: Well I did use the `i` argument to select the final result: `[which.max(g),]`. My answer could be shortened a little by doing `dd[,sum(g),by=f][which.max(V1),]`, but I used `list(g = ... )` to preserve the column names.

Comment: Sorry, that's a far better way of answering what was actually my question :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) syntax on a data.table, in this case:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>%
  group_by(f) %>%
  summarise (g = sum(g)) %>%
  top_n(1, g)

Source: local data table [1 x 2]

  f g
1 b 9
```

Comment: Works, though I'm quite curious as to how this can be fixed in a purely data.table way. Surprises me that seeing as the aggregation and grouping can be done in one data.table command, the final part requires something so different.