# data.table sum and subset

Tags: r, sum, filtering, data.table

I have a data.table that I am wanting to aggregate

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(year=c("2001","2001","2001","2002","2002","2002","2002"),
                  group=c("a","a","b","a","a","b","b"), 
                  amt=c(20,40,20,35,30,28,19))
```

I am wanting to `sum` the amt by year and group and then filter where the summed amt for any given group is greater than 100.

I've got the data.table sum nailed.

```
dt1[, sum(amt),by=list(year,group)]

   year group V1
1: 2001     a 60
2: 2001     b 20
3: 2002     a 65
4: 2002     b 47
```

I am having trouble with my final level of filtering.

The end outcome I am looking for is:

```
   year group V1
1: 2001     a 60
2: 2002     a 65
```

As `a) 60 + 65 > 100` whereas `b) 20 + 47 <= 100`

Any thoughts on how to achieve this would be great.

I had a look at this [data.table sum by group and return row with max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211800/data-table-sum-by-group-and-return-row-with-max-value) and was wondering whether or not their is an equally eloquent solution to my problem.

Comment: You should just aggregate again: `dt1[, sum(amt),by=list(year,group)][,list(year,V1,sum(V1)),by=group][V3>100,list(year,group,V1)]`

Comment: Fyi, a new, better `data.table` answer has been posted by thelatemail below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Single liner in `data.table`:

```
dt1[, lapply(.SD,sum), by=.(year,group)][, if (sum(amt) > 100) .SD, by=group]

#   group year amt
#1:     a 2001  60
#2:     a 2002  65
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
dt1 %>% 
  group_by(group, year) %>% 
  summarise(amt = sum(amt)) %>%
  filter(sum(amt) > 100)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data table [2 x 3]
#Groups: group
#
#  year group amt
#1 2001     a  60
#2 2002     a  65
```

Comment: This is quite an elegant solution, particularly for readability. The only thing I am not clear on is how might this get put into a new data.table.

Comment: @Dan You could add `... %>%  collect() -> dt2`

Answer (score 4):

This might not be an idea solution, but I would do that in several steps as follows:

```
dt2=dt1[, sum(amt),by=list(year,group)]
dt3=dt1[, sum(amt)>100,by=list(group)]
dt_result=dt2[group %in% dt3[V1==TRUE]$group,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two-liner. Find the subset of groups you want first

```
big_groups <- dt1[,sum(amt),by=group][V1>100]$group
dt1[group%in%big_groups,sum(amt),by=list(year,group)]
```

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I think my own preference goes the other way, among the data.table solutions :) The dplyr syntax is pretty nice for this case; much less repetition of variable names (Ala's and mine have `group` 3-4x).

Comment: Frank, it's tedious (and even confusing) to keep track of which groups are at what stage of your pipeline. I'd rather write `by=` one more time and be explicit. Besides, @latemail's answer is quite clear (and concise).

Comment: @Arun I agree and also think thelatemail's answer should be accepted. (I like all the other answers better than mine, but that's certainly the best.) I think it was posted a little after the OP chose this answer. I'll ping the latter.